# Config django compressor to not rename post processed files

Tags: django, sass, django-compressor

Django compressor renames my beautiful file names in ugly hashes in dev mode, I don't want to compress it, only process scss to css. How to config a django compressor to not rename sass files after processing them, while project runs with DEBUG = True?

Comment: There's no way that I'm aware of. The hashes are integral in how compressor handles processing and caching, even when just using the preprocessors. However, most people, myself included, consider it a *feature*: everytime you update a file, a new hash is generated so it's automatic cache-busting. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

Disable it in dev mode. In production you shouldn't need to care.

(It might be prudent to test dev with compression switched on before you deploy, however.)

Comment: how can i disable it in dev mode?